# Incorrect value when retrieving integer16 from CoreData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, integer

I have an attribute called `phoneNo` in my Core Data model, an `integer16`, and I need to of course save and load the value.

So I try saving the number the user types into a text field:

```
[myObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[textField.text integerValue]] forKey:@"mobileNo"];
```

Then I try and display the value like so:

```
label.text = [myObject.mobileNo stringValue];
```

Lets say I type in `123456789`; instead of displaying that, it shows `-13035`. I'm unsure if Im saving or loading wrongly, or both.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: you really shouldn't use a numeric field to store a telephone number. Sure, it's a number, but you never need to do math with it, and you could run into problems like this one. Use a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your datamodel (yourapp.xcdatamodeld) the type of your attribute phoneNo shouldn't be integer of 16 (from -32.768 to +32.768) which is not enough, it should be integer32 (-2.147.483.647 to +2.147.483.647) or integer64 if the guy type the country identifier like (+33) 1 23456789.